# How to implement “select all” check box in Google Forms?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I use "Check boxes" in Google Forms to take class attendance on a daily basis. If a student is present I tick the box. Mostly all the students are present. Is there a way to add a "Select All" button/ option in the google form which ticks all the students.

Is it possible to use Google Apps Script to do this? If yes, please provide an example code.

Screenshot of the checkboxes for attendance:

[image: img_checkBoxes]

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure there is a way to do that. I've used google forms a lot and I didn't see anything that can do that. I'll keep researching for you if you want, but otherwise, I'm not sure you can.

But the other thing you could make a everyone's here checkbox. Or an all of the above box. That would let you know that everyone was there. So I think this is the closest way to what you want.

Comment: Yeah, good call - "select all" is also a possible choice. But: you should address the issue of users selecting multiple checkboxes *and* the "select all" option. It will also be a plus if you provided a code sample for that for the reference of others.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it will solve the problem partially. But what I really want is to have a  "Select All" option which ticks the entire list and then I can uncheck the boxes of absent students.

Comment: I'll try to find out if there is a way to do that. If not, I don't think that's possible.